# Find rows without relations in sqlite3?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables. One called "members" and another called "homes" (should be household, but I suck in english). Those have a many-one relation (i.e. several members belong to one household). Those are linked together by members.homefk and homes.Id

Now, how can I find homes that don't belong to any members? I want this for house cleaning purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT homes.* 
FROM homes
LEFT JOIN members ON (members.home_id = home.id)
WHERE members.home_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a subquery to return all the homefk values, then select from homes where id not in the subquery,

In Oracle would look something like

SELECT h.id
  FROM homes h
 WHERE h.id NOT IN(
          SELECT DISTINCT(m.homefk)
            FROM members m)

Comment: I used Johans solution above. But a GREAT thanks for your time.

Comment: Kinda expensive when you're having thousands of `homes` with even more `members` to first select all members and then select all homes which id's are not present in the selected members..